# Missing .twig files in wordpress theme editor

Tags: templates, editor

I just started learning timber. Timber uses twig as its templating engine.

This is great but I have a problem with displaying all `.twig` files in the theme editor. I'm using VS code for my code development so I have no problem viewing and accessing `.twig` files there.

My problem is with the built in wordpress theme editor.

Do you know of a way to show all the file/folder structure when using the theme editor? starting with displaying `.twig` files but would also be nice to see all file/folder structure including, vendor, composer.json etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you need to do is update the filter with the "allowed" editor file types.

Here's what you'll need for TWIG:

```php
function add_custom_editor_file_types( $types ) {
    $types[] = 'twig';
    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'wp_theme_editor_filetypes', 'add_custom_editor_file_types' );
```

Of course, you can add any file type/extension you wish in the same manner. The editor UI will show the directory structure only where there are "editable" files.

EDIT:
Certain directories are excluded from being scanned for files, by default. One of these is `vendor`. This is likely because in some instances, the `vendor` dir will be huge and so loading and processing for this will have a cost associated with it.

To prevent `vendor` dir from being excluded, you can use the filter dedicated for that purpose:

```php
function unexclude_theme_editor_dirs( $exclusions ) {
    // default exclusions: 'CVS', 'node_modules', 'vendor', 'bower_components'
    $unExclude = [ 'vendor' ];
    return array_diff( $exclusions, $unExclude );
}
add_filter( 'theme_scandir_exclusions', 'unexclude_theme_editor_dirs' );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! liked and subscribed. Any idea how to display the vendor folder? (this folder is created with composer)

Comment: no problem! I've added an additional snippet so you can see the `vendor` dir too.

Comment: Fantastic!, everything that i needed, to bad I can't upvote the answer again. Upvoted the comment though =]

Comment: no sweat, glad it helps! :)